# TestFlight - Latest IPA Build getting disappear once processing stage done

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode8, itunes, testflight

After updating new TestFlight UI, getting confused how to give latest build to TestFlight Users.

Scenario 
- Create new IPA (Using Xcode 8.3.2) and upload on testFlight using Application Loader
- IPA uploaded successfully on TestFlight 
- Shows IPA in Activity tab and iTunes Connect Users Build section with processing mode.
- Once processing mode completed it's disappear from iTunes Connect Users Build section but available in Activity tab.
- Now I want Test With latest uploaded IPA but how to select that. There is no such open to select it.

Please go through with image so you will get better idea.

Today I have uploaded 2,3 and 4 build and it's shows in Activity tab that shows in image.
[image]

But now from iTuens connect user section, not able see those latest build so not able to move ahead with latest build testing.

[image]

Please assit me how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check email of your team agent. There must be an issue and apple sends an email regarding that issue

Comment: Okay, let me ask to team agent. Have you face this kind of error earlier ?

Comment: yes i have faced and solved by adding required keys in info.plist

Comment: required keys like? Would you please give me those keys?

Comment: like NSCameraUsageDescription and other fro hardware object getting. did you get email from team agent ?

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ No, I'm haven't received any email from team agent

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ: Are you taking about his key? NSCameraUsageDescription
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSContactsUsageDescription
NSCalendarsUsageDescription
NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription

Comment: Yes. I am talking about above keys.

Comment: What are the value of this keys?

Comment: I have added like  <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>This app needs access to photos.</string>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144514/discussion-between-kushal-vora-and-mohammad-ishaq).

Comment: Tried to upload again ? what happens ?

Comment: I have already added these keys in plist <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>This app needs access to photos.</string>

Comment: Than there must be an email from apple. Otherwise i can't get what is going on.

Comment: Okay ...Thanks @MOHAMMADISHAQ

Comment: Now going to upload new IPA with suggested new keys

Comment: Hello, I have uploaded latest build with all needed ipa but still no result

Comment: try to upload same version again and check if it gives error that version already existed.

Comment: It's giving error that, build is already available

Comment: Than bro there must be an error email. I have faced this many time. So ask your team agent to check it.

Comment: I have asked them but no any email received from iTuens to my team agent. And If I'm not wrong then team agent is main owner email account whom we are using

Comment: than send an email to apple , they will answer

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ; Hello, I have solved it by selecting App Store Distribution Certificate.

Comment: wao , Cheers man  :P